# Neo4J COALESCE in relationship

Tags: java, database, neo4j, cypher

I am trying to run a relationship creation but for some reason I cant use coalesce inside of my relationship query. Im completely stuck and some of this may be malformed but im trying to fix it one step at a time. here is my code

```
/* Get the kill assassin and student by relation UUID*/
'MATCH (a:Student)-[r:TARGET]->(t:Student) WHERE r.uuid = $uuid ' +
/* Lets Kill the student and set confirmed to true */
'SET r.confirmed = true, t.IsDead = true WITH ' +
/* Delete any teachers that may have the target of the student*/
'MATCH (t)<-[tr:TARGET]-(:Teacher) DELETE r ' +
/* Get the assassinated persons target. Set them as X. */
'MATCH (t)-[ar:TARGET]->(x:Student) WHERE ar.confirmed = false AND x.IsDead = false ' +
/* Lets deal with anyone who inherited our target if we are dead :(*/
'OPTIONAL MATCH (t)<-[sr:TARGET]-(ss:Student) WHERE sr.confirmed = false AND ss.IsDead = false ' +
/* Lets steal their kill node and set them as our new target unless of course someone decided to kill us and nab them */
'CREATE (COALESCE(t,a))-[nr:TARGET {killed:false,confirmed:false}]->(t) '
```

EDIT: I cleaned up my code A LOT. Just for the record coalesce cant be used in a relationship. Here is the cleaned up code for those wondering.

```
/**
     * a: The student who made the kill
     * v: The victim of the kill
     * r: the relationship between a and t
     * x: the victims target
     * tr (OPTIONAL) : the teacher who we hired to kill our target
     * ss: The person who will be inheriting t(victim)'s target
     */
    /* Get the Killer, set them as A AND set the Victim as T */
    'MATCH (a:Student)-[r:TARGET {uuid:$uuid,confirmed:false}]->(v:Student),' +
    /* Fetch the Victims Target and set them as x */
    '(v)-[:TARGET {confirmed:false}]->(x:Student {IsDead:false}) ' +
    /* Check if we hired a teacher to assassinate our target. Set the relationship to TR (teacher relation)*/
    'OPTIONAL MATCH (v)<-[tr:TARGET]-(:Teacher) ' +
    /* Fetch the alive person who has the target (in-case we died and then it went into review) */
    'MATCH (v)<-[sr:TARGET {confirmed:false}]-(ss:Student {IsDead:false}) ' +
    /* Create a relationship between SS and t */
    'CREATE (ss)-[:TARGET {killed:false,confirmed:false}]->(x) ' +
    /* Set the Kill Relationship to complete and kill the victim */
    'SET r.confirmed = true, v.IsDead = true,a.Balance = a.Balance + 3 ' +
    /* Delete the teacher relationship */
    'DELETE tr ', {uuid:uuid}
```

Comment: WTH is this graph supposed to be?

Comment: @manonthemat it's for a game called senior assassin. Check the repo here https://github.com/Volxz/Senior-Assassin-API-V1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use an expression inside that `CREATE` - but you *can* move that expression into a `WITH` statement to assign it to a variable, and then use that variable in your create.

The last line could be replaced by:

```
/* Lets steal their kill node and set them as our new target unless of course someone decided to kill us and nab them */
WITH COALESCE(t, a) as n, t
CREATE (n)-[nr:TARGET {killed:false,confirmed:false}]->(t)
```

Which compiles fine, but there are some other problems in the query I had to fix up first:

- Line 2, `SET r.comfirmed...` ends in a `WITH` but there's no variables after it
- Line 3, `MATCH (t)<-...` ends in a `DELETE` but the next line starts with a `MATCH` - you need a `WITH` in between the two

So the query I end up with is:

```
MATCH (a:Student)-[r:TARGET]->(t:Student) WHERE r.uuid = $uuid
/* Lets Kill the student and set confirmed to true */
SET r.confirmed = true, t.IsDead = true 
/* Delete any teachers that may have the target of the student*/
WITH a, t, r
MATCH (t)<-[tr:TARGET]-(:Teacher) DELETE r
/* Get the assassinated persons target. Set them as X. */
WITH a, t
MATCH (t)-[ar:TARGET]->(x:Student) WHERE ar.confirmed = false AND x.IsDead = false
/* Lets deal with anyone who inherited our target if we are dead :(*/
OPTIONAL MATCH (t)<-[sr:TARGET]-(ss:Student) WHERE sr.confirmed = false AND ss.IsDead = false
/* Lets steal their kill node and set them as our new target unless of course someone decided to kill us and nab them */
WITH COALESCE(t, a) as n, t
CREATE (n)-[nr:TARGET {killed:false,confirmed:false}]->(t)
```

But even then it looks wrong - the `COALESCE` will always resolve to `t` because to have gotten that far in the query `t` must have a value, so the last `CREATE` will just be creating a relationship between `t` and itself. Also: the `OPTIONAL MATCH` introduces the new variable `ss` but then the variable isn't used anywhere else (making the optional match somewhat redundant).

I'm guessing the `COALESCE` should be between `ss` and `a`, rather than `t` and `a` but it's hard to tell.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. This got me to my final solution which is much cleaner and organized. I will post an edit soon.